# Is it possible to set the content rating using the YouTube .NET API w/ Direct Upload?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube.net-api

If I'm upload some items that should have a content rating, how can I set that via the API?

Here's some tidbits of the code:

```
Dim newVideo As Video = Nothing
newVideo = New Video()
newVideo.Title = title
```

That's a part of it, can we set the rating ourselves within the API or is that functionality not there yet?

---

Also, if a video is blocked or flagged worldwide, do YouTube provide that in the upload successfully response, if a video uploads okay, I can get the ID, but can I also check to see if there's any complaints? I will ignore the Duplicate response for now. But I am more worried about the flagged or block as you only get three strikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting content rating isn't supported via the API.

If a video is not playable for any reason, including the reasons you mention, it will have an explanation of the problem in `yt:state`:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:state

Comment: Hello Jeff, Thanks for the answer, will the content rating be supported eventually? And is it possible to get the yt:state via the .NET API?

Comment: I don't think there's any plan to support content rating for arbitrary users' uploads. I'm sorry that I don't have any specific code to share for getting `yt:state` using the .NET API.